# Unknown segmentation fault error

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc

[image]

Can someone explain me what this error means?

If the image is not clear, this is the error:

```
Main: malloc.c:2372: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long) old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
```

Comment: Please post the related code here.

Comment: You have a bug which is causing heap corruption - run your code under valgrind in order to find the bug.

Comment: @PaulR Just curious: which part of the error tells you that it has to deal with heap corruption? (`malloc.c` and / or `sysmalloc`?) Thanks.

Comment: Please do not post code in images. That's just wrong.

Comment: @Unheilig: the error message is complaining because malloc's own internal data structures for managing the heap have become corrupted - this usually happens when something writes to an invalid address, e.g. writing to a dangling/wild pointer or running off the end of an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the memory allocation/deallocation functions have detected a serious problem in the heap, one that means using it is probably not safe to continue.

To understand this, realise that a heap almost always consists of data blocks *and* control information intermixed in memory (not totally required but most implementations would probably do it that way).

If you write beyond the end of an allocated block, you're therefore likely to corrupt some control information, such as with:

```
char *twoBytes = malloc(2);
memset (twoBytes, '\0', 10000);
```

Even assuming there's some free space at the end of the two bytes to make the allocations efficient (and you, as a developer, should *never* assume this), writing ten thousand bytes will almost certainly cause some severe damage.

Unfortunately, errors in the heap are rarely detected close to where they happen, so you'll need to examine your code for places where you may be writing beyond the ends of buffers. Another alternative is to use a tool like `valgrind` to detect suspect writes.